# How to use the dot command (.) in my custom command?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have written a simple batch file `mycmd.bat`, to open up explorer. I've added the file in the appropriate path. The content of the file is:

```
explorer
```

Now I want to use this bat file to open up any directory. So I navigate to the required directory and run my command:

```
D:\MyFolder>mycmd .
```

If I have Visual Studio Code installed then if I wanted to open the directory with VS Code then I'd do:

```
D:\MyFolder>code .
```

I want similar approach for my custom command.

Now if I run `D:\MyFolder>mycmd .` it opens up my `Libraries` folder. Not the folder I am at right now which is `D:\MyFolder`.

(For me Libraries is the default folder that opens up when I open explorer by clicking the yellow explorer icon at my taskbar.)

Comment: Uhm... What is the question? How to start the batch file?

Comment: [edit] your question and show us the content of the `mycmd` file

Comment: the content of the mycmd.bat is just 'explorer' as for now. But I'll do more complex operations in that directory using that batch file. So I'll be adding more lines to that mycmd.bat file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a batch-file for that. Navigating to the directory and typing (into the commandline I assume you to take to navigate) `explorer .` opens the explorer view of that folder.

An alternative if you are running this in a batch-file you could also use `explorer %cd%`. The environmental variable `cd` stores the  path of the <del>current</del> callers (Thanks for the correction by WasteD!) directory.
So it uses the value from where you called the file i.e. the directory you are currently in *or* after you used `cd anotherFolder` it will use this new path.

To change your "custom command" you could also add `"%~1"` to the same line `explorer` currently stands in:

`explorer "%~1"`

This will take the first argument of your batch-file -> in this case `.` without potential surreounding quotes and add it after the explorer command as first argument.

Comment: `%cd%` stands for the callers directory not for the `.bat` just  wanted to say this :)

Comment: Yeah the directory the batch-file is in from the program POV right? So starting the batch from `C:` and then using `cd Users` should lead to `C:\Users` beeing stored in there. Should I rewrite that part in the answer?

Comment: No I think for example if the caller runs it from `C:` like so: `C:\Scripts\mybat.bat` then if you use `echo %cd%` it will output `C:` I think...

Comment: Aye true! Thanks for the correction. Editted properly :)